# How to insert rows before populating of data in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am developing in CodeIgniter, and I would like to add rows first before I populate data in excel sheet.

The problem is that rows are not adding despite I used several methods.

I already tried using:

```
`$object->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(1,5);`
```

And

```
    $table_columns = array("Student 
 ID","Lastname","Firstname","Middlename","Total No. of Days","Days Present","Days Absent");
    
    $column = 0;
    $row = 4;
    foreach($table_columns as $field){
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $field);
            $column++;                
    }
```

But still it does not even add rows before the table columns.